# Where's the location of the eclipse.ini file?

Tags: eclipse

I know this is a silly question, but I can't seem to locate the eclipse.ini file for the IDE. I've looked in my installation directory as well as searched for the file itself in file explorer and can't find it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What platform are you on (macOS, Linux, Windows)? It is always in the same folder as the Eclipse executable but on some platforms this is not easy to find.

Answer (score 36):

It should be right beside the executable.

[image]

Comment: in my case the file hasn't got .ini

Comment: If you use eclipse sts i.e. eclipse spring tool suite, then the name will sts.ini or similar, instead of eclipse.ini.

Comment: right click on the eclipse file and select properties. It may say Type of file: Configuration settings (.ini) if you're in File Explorer

Answer (score 8):

[image]

**For MacOs Users**:

- Search for Eclipse in finder.
- Right-click or secondary click or Control-click on Eclipse App as shown on the picture. Click on "Show package contents"
- you can find the eclipse.ini under Contents>Eclipse folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### In Linux

I give you three possible methods:

- The most effective method is using the command `locate`. Write in terminal

  `locate eclipse.ini`
- Apart from that, as said in @JoeC answer, it should be in the same
  directory as the `eclipse` **executable**. A link to the `eclipse`
  executable is found in `/usr/bin` , therefore typing in terminal
  following command will show you the directory of the executable

  `ls -l /usr/bin | grep 'eclipse'`
- The last option is to find the executable directory by following the icon in your *Menu Editor* (but I think that depends highly on your Linux flavour)

Answer (score 0):

### **In Windows:**

I can see it as 'SpringToolSuite4' config file just below the executable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I searched my system completely and found it in "User". User had two more folders, in my laptop it was Lenovo and Public. I found a folder named eclipse in Lenovo, clicked on it and got another folder named java-2022-032 in which the file eclipse.ini was present. Name of file was eclipse and its type was "configuration setting". This is your file. (You can also see the properties to check if its type is .ini or not.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For windows: If you have installed eclipse using the installer in the default location, that would be *C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\eclipse*