# Why ECLIPSE NEON is so slow on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ide

I'm using the eclipse neon IDE and I put it on the path: `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` and i am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Java 8. The problem is that when I write in the eclipse editor, this is going too slow. For example, I just typed and in the editor it still does not end.

How can I solve it?

Thx!

Comment: Buy a faster computer. Stop extraneous programs. Look in `top`, if eclipse/java is using all of the cpu then see option 1.

Comment: In fact I have no computation problems and I have started only eclipse and it remains the same.

Comment: If you're sure there's nothing else running, then you could raise this with the makers of Eclipse.  You're unlikely to get a good answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764

Answer (score 1):

Try **Netbeans**, or **IntelliJ IDEA**.

A quick browse over the Interwebs shows that quite a lot of people are complaining about Eclipse slowness. Some have every manner of trick and configuration change to help speed it up. OK, you can put yourself thru all that hassle if you want, ***or***, you can just switch to something that already works fine out of the box.

I had Eclipse Oxygen for PHP running on a CentOS 7 VM with 2G allocated RAM. I admit, that's pretty low memory, but that's the way it has to be right now. Eclipse ran so slowly, I finally gave up and killed the process from the command line.

I installed the latest Netbeans 8.2, and it not only installed more cleanly (no Java error messages, and it put an icon on the desktop), it ran *PERFECTLY* without changing a thing!

I eventually changed a couple of parameters, but the point is, *I didn't need to change a thing to get decent performance.* Even on a low-ram system, it ran plenty fast enough.

Don't blame the hardware. Not everybody has the money to buy the latest and greatest and fastest machines available, and software developers should not expect it. With some exceptions, if your application can not run adequately on 2G of ram, you are doing something wrong.

The Eclipse developers are doing something *terribly* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue with eclipse oxygen.
After a some research over different forums I found the following solution.

**Step 1** : Open eclipse.ini file. If you find difficulty in locating the file, see this question [Where's the location of the eclipse.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795137/wheres-the-location-of-the-eclipse-ini-file)

**Step 2** : In eclipse.ini search for below 2 variables

> -Xms
>
> -Xmx

Xms indicates minimum ram that should be allocated to eclipse.

Xmx indicates maximum ram that should be allocated to eclipse.

**Step 3** :Increment both the values. You can set the value as per your choice. Below is my preference.

> -Xms512m
>
> -Xmx2048m

Here

> m indicates megabytes, if you don't specify m it will consider bytes by default.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing to do would be to re-install eclipse, and if that does not work you could try to download an older version of eclipse. It could also be slow because your computer is slow.