# Distributing eclipse with UI customizations

Tags: eclipse

I would like to use Eclipse in an intro programming class. Is there some way I can make some kind of preferences file or some such that I can distribute with it that would set defaults for:

1. which buttons are in the toolbar
2. which menus are enabled in the application
3. which context-menus are enabled
4. what kinds of completions are available

   1. I'd like it to start with only completing words from the current document

      - that is no Java API completions or code generation or whatever

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Eclipse Preferences File](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Preferences/article.html). All you need to do is import preferences into your workspace.

You can also export the workspace folder itself & publish Eclipse together with a default workspace folder, which will contain all the preferences.

Then create a shortcut to start eclipse with `-data <path to your workspace>` parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following:

- Install Eclipse
- Put the configuration files and workspace under version control and commit.
- Configure Eclipse as required.
- Check all the changes in the version control to understand what configuration files are relevant to my changes.
- Continue as Zilvinas is suggesting.

Comment: I know I can choose where the workspace goes, but where will the configuration files be (so that I can put them under version control)?

Comment: As far as I know there is the Eclipse.ini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795137/wheres-the-location-of-the-eclipse-ini-file for things like heap size configuration, there is the workspace itself (you'll probably only need this one) and then there are per-project metadata (for a Java project: .settings folder, .classpath and .project files).

Answer (score 1):

Look into Eclipse [Oomph](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/may/article3.php). It essentially automates all the tasks that you need to do to set up a fresh dev environment.

Also of interest are [Yatta profiles](https://www.yatta.de/profiles/) which do a similar thing based off Oomph.

They're pretty easy to set up and publish. Get your local eclipse working, record to a profile, publish the profile, get your students to consume said profile. We've used these in a professional environment to more easily on-board new devs!